# En una consulta ¿Es posible llenar un campo con todos los registros de otra tabla?

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy haciendo una consulta y en un campo de esa consulta quiero concatenar o sacar todos los datos que están en otra tabla. ¿Es posible hacer esto?

Esta es la consulta que estoy realizando:

```sql
SELECT r.id_resg as 'CLAVE RESGUARDO',

       -- AQUI QUISIERA QUE SALIERAN TODOS LOS CAMPOS DE MI OTRA TABLA,
       concat(resp.id_personal,' ' ,p.nombre,' ',p.Puesto) as 'RESGUARDANTE(S)'

  from articulos art 
  join art_resguardo artresg 
  join resguardos r 
  join responsables resp 
  join personal p 
    on r.id_resg=resp.id_resg 
   and resp.id_personal=p.id_personal 
   and art.no_serie=artresg.no_serie 
   and r.id_resg=artresg.id_resg;
```

Comment: A simple vista (y sin saber la estructura de tus tablas) parece que esa consulta hará lo que quieres. ¿Cómo falla lo que tienes? ¿Recibes algún error?

Comment: no recibo ningun error pero esta consulta me arroja varias filas ya que como depende de los registros de otras tablas muestra una fila por cada coincidencia que encuentra como si fuera un producto cartesiano y lo que me gustaria hacer es que todo salga en un solo registro. no se si me explique bien

Comment: ¿has probado a usar LEFT JOIN?

Answer (score 0):

En MySQL al menos sí que se puede. No sé que motor de bases de datos estas usando pues no está claro en tu pregunta.

En el caso de MySQL la sintaxis sería más bien algo parecido a esto

```
INSERT INTO `tabla_donde_quieras_insertar` (`clave_resguardo`, 'resguardantes`)
SELECT
    r.id_resg as `clave_resguardo`,
    CONCAT(...) as `resguardantes`

FROM
    ...

WHERE
    ...
```

Asegurate de que la consulta esté bien hecha, ya que de allí tendrás que sacar la *clave_resguardo* y *resguardantes* (Les he cambiado el nombre a cómo creo que tendrá que llamarse el campo en base de datos)

Answer (score 0):

Ya solucione mi problema utilice el GROUP_CONCAT para concatenar todas las filas de una tabla junto con una clausula where para restringir solo los que ocupo.
Gracias por sus respuestas